# What is the difference when measuring in units rather than meters?

Tags: postgis

I have a function that takes a point and compares it with lines that are stored in PostGIS and then gets the line closest to the point. Initially I did not transform the data because I did not think that it would matter when I want to get the minimum distance. I thought that small distances (up to 100m) would not need transformation but I was wrong! Sometimes it gets a line that is not the closest one even if the compared distances are 1.2m and 2.5m. I discovered that and I re-designed the SQL command to transform the point and line to the local UTM zone and now its working fine.

I would appreciate it if someone could explain to me how is this possible at such a small scale.  Why did PostGIS think that a line 2.5m away from my point is closer than a line 1.2m away? Perhaps an emphasis on UNITS vs metric unit usage?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll have to put your mental visualization cap on, but remember, lines of longitude converge at the poles. So, a 5x5 square at the equator squeezes down to a narrow rectangle at the poles. Effectively, a "unit" of unprojected horizontal distance covers less and less real distance the further north you go. This is probably the source of the discrepancy you are seeing.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using PostGIS 2.x, you might like to know that `ST_Distance` will return the ellipsoidal distance for `geography` types.  But if you have an unprojected `geometry` type (such as SRID 4326), then you are subject to the distortion that entails.

You can visualise the distortion quite easily by viewing the Earth as [*plate carrée*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equirectangular_projection) - towards the poles, you'll see that east-west distances appear stretched.  Away from the equator, it's quite likely that an east-west line of 1.2 metres appears longer than a north-south line of 2.5 metres.